# My program keeps crashing when I make one calculation in one Activity and then tring to pass the result to another Activity

Tags: android

I have a problem with my app. More precisely, the app keeps crashing when  it's executed in the SDK.

Here is the code of the first Activity, where I perform the first calculation:

```
 package com.example.bart.fit_up;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class LooseWeight extends AppCompatActivity {

 TextView TotalCal;
 EditText numb2;
 Spinner ActLvl;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loose_weight);

    numb2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.WeightIn);
    ActLvl = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ActLvl);
    TotalCal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultBox);

    final Spinner ActLvl = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ActLvl);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(LooseWeight.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lvl));



      myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ActLvl.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    Button calcBtn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CalcBtn);
    calcBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {
            float a = Float.valueOf(numb2.getText().toString());
            float b = a * 24;
            float c = b * Float.valueOf(ActLvl.getSelectedItem().toString());
            float d = c - 500;
            TotalCal.setText(Float.toString(d));

            Intent inte = new Intent(LooseWeight.this, FurtherCalculations.class);
            inte.putExtra("e", d);
            startActivity(inte);


        }
    });

      Button extra = (Button)findViewById(R.id.advanBtn);
      extra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),FurtherCalculations.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

 }
 }
```

Here is the second Activity, where the calculation is meant to be automatically executed when the user chooses one of three options from the Spinner.

```
  package com.example.bart.fit_up;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class FurtherCalculations extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView res1;
TextView res2;
TextView res3;
String e;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_further_calculations);

    res1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iloscBialka);
    res2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iloscWegli);
    res3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iloscTluszczy);

    final Spinner typeOfBody = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bodyType);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(FurtherCalculations.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dietT));
     myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    typeOfBody.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    Intent inte1 = getIntent();
    e = inte1.getStringExtra("e");



    if (typeOfBody.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Ectomorph"))
    {
        float f = Float.valueOf(e);
        float g = f / 100;
        float h = g * 25;
        res1.setText(Float.toString(h));

        float i = h / 100;
        float j = i * 55;
        res2.setText(Float.toString(j));

        float k = j / 100;
        float l = k * 20;
        res3.setText(Float.toString(l));

    }
    if (typeOfBody.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Mesomorph")){

        float f = Float.valueOf(e);
        float g = f / 100;
        float h = g * 30;
        res1.setText(Float.toString(g));

        float i = h / 100;
        float j = i * 40;
        res2.setText(Float.toString(i));

        float k = j / 100;
        float l = k * 30;
        res3.setText(Float.toString(l));

    }
}

}
```

The crash happens when I put a number in the weightIn EditText ,choose the actLvl from the Spinner and press the calcBtn Button to do the calculation.

Before it was happening when I pressed the extra Button, which should take the result of the first calculation to the second Activity and perform another calculation by chosing on of three different options from the Spinner (each option a different calculation)

Comment: You need to add callstack of the exception.

Comment: And watchout as NPEs are quickly closed :-)

Comment: What is R.array.lvl?

Comment: R.array.lvl is assigned in string and has values for choosing activity level on the first activity.

Comment: Sorry to be bit silly but what is the NPE and what is the callstack of the exception.... sorry as you can see I'm not good with coding. Especially with android studio.... sorry.

Comment: Did you try debugging it line by line? See where it fails

Comment: NPE is Null Pointer Exception and callstack is the exception trace that you get in the AndroidMonitor tab which shows the sequence of calls which leads to the exception.